# Retrieve $_SESSION variables by using key word contained in the full variable name

Tags: php, session

I am trying to get all $_SESSION variables which contain one keyword of my choosing. For example:

```
$_SESSION['itemNumber'];
$_SESSION['itemColor'];
$_SESSION['itemWeight'];
```

As you can guess I want to get all items which contain the 'item' keyword.

Comment: Why didn't you built the array like: `$_SESSION['item']['number']` - `$_SESSION['item']['color']`

Comment: The idea of my question is flexibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through each item in the SESSION;
Check that 'item' exists within the key name;
If it does then show the variable name and it's value

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
{     
     if(strpos($key,'item') !== false)
        echo $key. ": ".$val. "<br>";
}
```

Replace the echo, with whatever you want to do with those variables.

Comment: an explanation for your code will imp[rove the quality of this answer: it was flagged due to the length being so short...

Comment: There we go, added some more info

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
foreach( $_SESSION as $key => $value)
{
        if( strpos($key, 'item') )
        {
                // do what you want to do with $_SESSION[$key]
        }
}
```